# RecyclerView: itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE) hides all items below the itemView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have implemented a favorites list in Android and have created a **recyclerView** for it. In the **recyclerView** each item being displayed have a button named `btnRemove` to remove the item from the favorite list.

After clicking `btnRemove` of the corresponding item:

1. If the item is at bottom, only that item hides from the list.

**BUT**

2. If the item lies on the top or in the center, it hides along with all items below it. ***This is my issue***

Following is my code for setting RecyclerView inside my activity class:

```
    RecyclerView rv_fav=v.findViewById(R.id.listFavourites);
    rv_fav.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext()));
    FavListAdapter adapter=new FavListAdapter(this.getContext());
```

Inside `FavListAdapter` class where I am hiding the views by following code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

...
...

     holder.btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                            fav_list.remove(position);

                            holder.itemView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            //holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));   //I also tried this but got the same result




                }
            });
    }
```

I also tried the following code but the result was same:

```
holder.itemView.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first remove the item from your list:

```
favoriteList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
```

Then notify adapter of changes:

```
  notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
  notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(),favoriteList.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Very Intresting!!!

You have to notify to the RecyclerViewAddapter about data change.Since here your button onClick() is inside Inner class so i am trying to get your FavListAdapter object by FavListAdapter.this.

Just add one line inside your onClick() method ' like Following

```
holder.btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                            fav_list.remove(position);
                            FavListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();  // do this if your ViewHolder is inside FavListAdapter.
                            


                }
            });
```

Note: No need to set visibility to itemview as it is gone.